# GORM doesn't create ForeignKey column

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I'm trying to setup relation between two models on PostgreSQL database using Go and gorm.

Here is my code, first model:

#### Trip.go

```golang
package model

import "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"

// Trip models
type Trip struct {
    gorm.Model
    TripName        string
    TripDescription string
}
```

Second model:

#### TripKeyPoints.go

```golang
package model

import "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"

// TripKeyPoint models
type TripKeyPoint struct {
    gorm.Model
    KPName        string
    KPDescription string
    TripID        Trip
}
```

Part of code from a file which runs migrations and initializes all

```golang
    db.DropTableIfExists(&User{}, &model.Trip{}, &model.TripKeyPoint{})
    db.AutoMigrate(&User{}, &model.Trip{}, &model.TripKeyPoint{})
    db.Model(&model.TripKeyPoint{}).AddForeignKey("trip_id", "trips(id)", "CASCADE", "CASCADE")
```

Users models is just an addon but I leave it in this snippet.
Due to many tests, I drop tables at the beginning.

Here is what I receive when i run the code:

```
?[35m(C:/golang_lab/golang-gorm-tutorial/users.go:36)?[0m
?[33m[2019-09-21 18:40:34]?[0m ?[31;1m pq: column "trip_id" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist ?[0m
```

And yeah that's true, when I log into postgres in table trip_key_points there isn't column with a foreign key.

What I need to do, I want to have one TRIP object and then assign other TripKeyPoints.

Any idea what why? Or how can I force GORM to create this column?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I explicitly define foreign key column:

```
// TripKeyPoint models
type TripKeyPoint struct {
    gorm.Model
    KPName        string
    KPDescription string
    TripID        uint `gorm:"TYPE:integer REFERENCES trips"`
}
```

Comment: You are a legend, have been trying to figure this out for the last hour. Thanks!

Comment: How would you create a list of foreign keys using this paradigm?

Answer (score 0):

try to edit your struct like this :

```
// TripKeyPoint models
type TripKeyPoint struct {
    gorm.Model
    KPName        string
    KPDescription string
    TripID        Trip `gorm:"foreignkey:TripId"`
}
```

Comment: I verified this one and it's not working. But unfortunately, it should due to documentation. Thanks